# Derailleur replacement recommendation

Tags: derailleur, hybrid-bike

I have been experiencing some issues with my rear derailleur. I played around with it quite a bit to adjust it correctly. Finally after giving up, I took it to the shop and the guy showed me that the rear derailleur is bent, plus the chain is stretched. So, I am considering changing it along with the chain.

I need some recommendations, not necessarily on the exact model, but the type of derailleurs. The person at the shop recommended Shimano Deore. But I noticed that these seem to be for mountain bikes. My bike is more of a hybrid (if that is what it is called) [La pierre Shaper 100](http://www.culturevelo.com/Shaper-100-9577).

Would regular road bike derailleur's work? I use the bike mainly for commute (36kms/20miles daily).

Would really welcome suggestions, thoughts, etc?

Thanks

Edit. Down the line I might consider changing the rear cassette from 8 to 9, or maybe 10, will the front derailleur have to match up with the new cassette at the back and the new rear derailleur to make sure each gear in the front has a big enough range for gears at the back without the chain touching the front derailleur?

Comment: Shimano Deore sounds quite right for your bike and usage.

Comment: You should also factor in that you may need to change your rear cassette if it's also worn down too much by the worn chain. It may skip regularly with a new chain installed.

Comment: Most hybrids use quite a lot of MTB components in the drivetrain -- even those with road components elsewhere.  For example hybrid riders tend to like a triple chainring, and road triples can give a bit much at the top end.

Comment: The shop probably recommended the Deore as its on the shelf. You could spend $25+$5 delivery for the 'correct' one (and wait a day or two), or $35 and have a much better quality component installed immediately.

Answer (score 2):

According to your link - your bike is 8 speed.
The bog standard (excludes the upper-end XT variant) Deore derailleur has only ever been produced in 9/10 speed.
And one assumes - you are looking at the latest 10 speed version.
An 8 speed chain is significantly wider than a 10 speed chain. Consequently, the chain may have problems with not only the jockey wheels of a 10 speed derailleur but also passing through the cage of the mechanism.
Additionally, MTB rear mechs - can run much wider range of gears and therefore *can* have a longer cage to facilitate this. With the range of gears on the link - you would require a medium cage rear mech.

You bike runs the Shimano 2300 range. And I would recommend sticking to this or something like the Shimano Claris range. These are also road specific & probably cheaper than a Deore rear mech.

Comment: If you change the cassette to a different speed, you will need to change shifters too! Rear Derailleur 8 or 9sp is very little difference and a 9sp Deore might work fine on an 8sp chain and cassette.

Comment: Weird. I don't see why the answer was down-scored. It is technically correct. @Roka What you appear to be recommending is the OP accepts the mismatched derailleur from the bike shop. That's just plain wrong. As quoted above - "one assumes - you are looking at the latest 10 speed version". The OP also does not mention wishing to upgrade to 9 or 10 speed either - so one assumes wishing to retain current 8 speed drive train with best compatibility rather than mixing and matching different speed drive trains.

Comment: 9sp derailleurs work absolutely fine on 8sp chain and cassette.  It is the chain and cassette that cannot be mismatched.

Comment: It isn't technically correct.  A 10 speed mountain deraileur uses different cable pull than 7-9 speed in Shimano (road or mountain).

Comment: The explanation is still wrong, and 9-speed Deore is both available and compatible with 8-speed. The part about 8-speed Deore not existing is irrelevant, but also wrong.

Comment: just as a point Claris is the new 2300 and has the designation of 2400. It brings STI leavers to 2300. Both 2300 and Claris used a longer than standard cage to accommodate a mtb cassette as it was aimed at entry level.

Comment: @Henry A longer cage is primarily for the triple. The lower pulley of the cage does not track the cassette width; it picks up *slack*. What causes more *slack*? Certainly not a *bigger* cog on the cassette! The granny ring in the front!  If you shift to a granny ring with a short-cage derailleur, and shift to a small cog, the derailleur will flip all the way backwards, causing the bottom of the chain to ride the upper pulley/jockey. When you shift to a big *cog*, like a 34T and a big chainring, your cage straightens out, more or less. At that point, the cage length is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't accept a Deore mech as a replacement. ask for a 2300 or 2400 (Claris) mech. Not only are they cheaper, but also the correct item.

If the chain is stretched replace it ASAP, as this will soon start to wear both the cassette and then the chainrings, which will end up costing a significant amount to replace.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and suggestions. As much as I'd like to I should keep my budget to a minimum, so it seems that claris might be a good option. One question though, it is apparently an entry level derailler. What does that mean? I bike 36 kms a day, in my opinion a fair amount. So is entry level a good choice?

Comment: Entry Level is perfectly acceptable. When you move up to the bigger and better groupsets, you will gain longevity to an extent, but with an equivalent price tag. The bigger change is in shift quality and speed, more gears and lighter weight. One thing I would point out, if you want to go to a 10speed cassette, it will require a new groupset as a whole, new chain, cassette, front and rear mechs, shifters and crankset. With the possible need to replace the rear wheel, as the cassette may not fit.

Comment: Yes, would love to have smooth changing gears, but for the moment, changing everything on the cycle is out of my budget for the moment. I am going with the Claris groupset for now.

Comment: Claris derailleurs are made-in-south-Asia junk, not made in Japan. Avoid Shimano-anything that is not stamped Japan! Also, the cage inner plate plastic.  If you can make a better derailleur work on your 8 speed system, do it. If chain width is an issue, don't use a 6-7-8 speed chain; put on a 9.

Comment: @Kaz .. I beg to differ .. it's a little prejudiced to say not "made in Japan" is junk .. Shimano has a major factory in M'sia .. even some Deore parts are made there .. but that said I must agree that I feel much better when my parts arrive and I see a "Japan" stamped on it :)